# Scale 4K Apple TV app in simulator to pixel accurate

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to test an application for the Apple TV 4k. In order to test it the best possible way, I want to scale the simulator to be 'pixel accurate.'

For some reason Apple TV 4k simulator does not resize to the real Pixel accurate size. The iPhone X however does scale to the correct size.

I did scale to `Pixel accurate` or `cmd+2`

Does anyone have the same problem, and how can I scale the Apple TV 4k to the `Pixel accurate` size.

i'm using XCode Version 9.1 beta (9B46)
[image: Apple TV 4K simulator scale issue]